# Basic Sorting of class objects by the object property

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a list of accounts for a little thing I'm making and I want to sort them by the balance each one has:
This is what I have, the accounts are in data and I want to sort them and repopulate listtext which is a listbox that should hopefully show the back in order after they are sorted, unfortunately its not working and I can't see why its just a basic bubble sort

```
private void sortingmethodtwo()
        {
            Account tempvar;
            double[] storeArray = new double[count];
            for (int i = 0; i< count; i++)
            {
                for ( int j = 0; j<count; j++)
                {
                    if (data[i].getBalance() > data[j].getBalance())
                    {
                        tempvar = data[i];
                        storeArray[i] = storeArray[j];
                        data[i] = data[j];
                        data[j] = tempvar;

                    }
                }
            }
            listText.Items.Clear();
            foreach (Account a in data)
            {
                listText.Items.Add(a.getAccRefNo() + " " + a.getName());
            }

        }
```

Can anyone shine some light for me?

Comment: A bubblesort has to be repeated until all elements are in order, e.g. by setting a flag each time any two elements need to be swapped and then repeating until the flag is not set. That being said, there is no reason for you to write your own sorting algorithm when you have LINQ's [OrderBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37017087/how-to-use-orderby-in-linq).

Comment: You have both `i` and `j` loops going from `0` to `count`.  This doesn't even guarantee that `i < j`.    To guarantee that `i < j` change the second loop `for (int j = i + 1; j<count; j++)`  Note:  `j = i + 1` instead of `j = 0`.  (And get rid of `storeArray`; it appears to be a distraction from sorting `data`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lambda to sort it:

```cs
var sortedList=data.OrderBy(x=>x.getBalance()).ToList();
```

if you want to by another property change the `x=>x.getBalance()` to that.

For your buble sort, your problem is that actually this is not the bubble sort algorithm at all. Bubble compares the current element to the next one and swaps them if not ordered, counting the number of swaps. It continues passing through the data until there are no more swaps.

Your loop is comparing inner to outer loop variables, you should be comparing inner to the inner +1.

Comment: toList(); should be ToList(); - correct answer though

Comment: Corrected. Too reliant on VS I think.

Comment: Yup - I feel you :D. Needs a stack overflow plugin